# $a \circ' b = b^{-1} \circ a \circ b^{2}$ Show that for every $a, b \in G$, the equations $x \circ' a = b$ and $a \circ' x =b $ has unique solutions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G, \circ)$ be a group. Define a new binary operation $\circ'$ on $G$ as follows, $$a \circ' b = b^{-1} \circ a \circ b^{2}$$ Show that for every $a, b \in G$, the equations $x \circ' a = b$ and $a \circ' x =b $ has unique solutions.

First part is easy since $a^{-1}xa^{2}=b$, so $x = aba^{-2}$

But I am stuck in second part, here is what I tried.

We want to find $x$ such that $x^{-1}ax^{2}= b$, Firstly I just considered $f_{x} = x^{-1}ax^{2}$, and saw what is happening with it for different $x$, I found if $x = a^{n}$ then $f_x = a^{n+1}$, also clearly $x = a^{-1}$ we get identity element and also tried some other things, which seems irrelevant. So, it did not helped much, Then I considered $ax^{2} = xb$ and tried to simplify this, for this firstly I replaced $x$ by $xb$, which gave $axbxb = xb^{2}$ or $axbx = xb$ and I tried to manipulate this in more ways, but did not get anything, finally I just started guessing and putting, which did not worked.

Also is there a general way to solve equations in group.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have edited it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This as written above is not always true though.

Let us consider $S_3$ acting on $\{1,2,3\}$, and let $a$ be the following element:
$a(1)=3$; $a(3)=1$; $a(2)=2$. Then as $e^{-1}ae^2 =a$ already, by the Pigeonhole Principle, there is a $b \in S_3$ such that there is no $x \in S_3$ satisfying $x^{-1}ax^2 =b$ if there is a $y \in S_3; y \not = e$ that satisfies $y^{-1}ay^2=a$.

Take $y$ as follows: $y(1)=2$; $y(2)=3$; $y(3)=1$. Then $y^{-1}ay^2=a$. [Indeed, first note the equation $y^2=y^{-1}$,
and the note $y^{-1}ay^2(1)= y^{-1}a(3) = y^{-1}(1) = 3$;
$y^{-1}ay^2(3) = y^{-1}a(2) = y^{-1}(2) = 1$; and so $y^{-1}ay^2(2) = 2$.]

Comment: Explicitly, there is no solution to $((13)\sigma)^{\sigma} = (12)$. $\sigma\neq e$, and a quick check shows that neither $(123)$ nor $(132)$ work; and if $\sigma$ is of order $2$, then $(13)\sigma$ is of order dividing $3$, hence cannot be conjugate to $(12)$.

Comment: First line in the solution prompt me to ask, Is there any restriction that one can impose to make this thing work, for example one obvious way is choosing $(G,\circ)$ to be abelian in that case, both of these operations are same. But is there any weaker condition or something. Thanks for help.